# DialogFlow V2 API - Webhook response was empty

Tags: php, dialogflow-es

My webhook is not getting invoked from Dialogflow and always returning an error

> Webhook call failed. Error: Webhook response was empty.

When I use CURL/POST MAN with the dialogflow request the response I get is according to the documentation.

```
{
"fulfillmentMessages": [
  {
"text": {
"text": [
  "Hi, how can I help?"
],
}
}
],
"fulfillmentText": "Hi, how can I help?",
"outputContexts": [],
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure the URL you have set for fulfillment is the same one you're using in your tests and that it responds correctly to POST messages that are formatted with the webhook request JSON.

Check your server logs to see if there is an error being generated when your webhook is called.